# Android: IOException: Permission denied

Tags: java, android, permissions, ioexception

I'm creating/saving file on SD card. This is the code:

```
File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
public void btnsave_clicked(View v) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
     File f;
      f=new File(sdDir, "deposit.dma");
      if(!f.exists())
      f.createNewFile();
...
}
```

But when I click the button, it throws "Permission denied".
Don't ask me for add uses-permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I've already added this in Manifest.

What should I do?
LogCat info:

```
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2168)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2163)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    ... 11 more
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1257)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    at org.brotheroftux.depositmaster.MainActivity.btnsave_clicked(MainActivity.java:43)
10-19 20:25:14.681: E/AndroidRuntime(29016):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: I would start by posting the logcat errors so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Please post the logcat output. Also, make sure that the `<uses-permission ...>` line is in the correct place in the manifest. Also, is this on a real device or on an emulator?

Comment: uses-permission should be present directly in the `<manifest> ... </manifest> `tag.

Comment: It sounds like you have connected the storage card to the PC. You need to disconnect it if you can see as a new drive in your pc.

Comment: Yeah, uses-permission is inn right place. It throws this even when I detach the device from PC

Comment: Just for sure please add your Manifest.

Comment: No problem, see mfrankli's post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Android Environment doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

> Applications should not directly use this top-level directory, in order to avoid polluting the user's root namespace. Any files that are private to the application should be placed in a directory returned by Context.getExternalFilesDir, which the system will take care of deleting if the application is uninstalled. Other shared files should be placed in one of the directories returned by getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String).

In other words, this is not really a good practice (although perhaps you have some very good reason; the context isn't very clear).

Additionally, as Cthulhu and Ted Hopp commented, make sure the permission is in the correct location in the manifest.

Comment: Okey I'll try this method, but uses-permission is in right place.

Answer (score 4):

Some SD and MicroSD cards have write-protect switches on them.  If yours has one, make sure that it is not write-protected.

Also, after you plug your phone in, make sure you have not selected "Turn on USB storage."  This will mount your SD card for access by your PC and disable writing by your device.

You can check this by swiping the notification bar down from the top.  Mine says "USB Connected" which is ok, but "Turn on USB storage" should not be enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Was pulling my hair out.  Never realized that setting the phone to USB storage mode would lock the phone's access to the card.