# Copy /system/app/*.apk to sdcard programmatically

Tags: android, copy, apk

i have path of one apk "/system/app/Gallery2.apk" and i want to copy this on sdcard. i implement copy method

```
 public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

but it shows IOException

i pass values

```
 try {
                    File file =new File( pm.getApplicationInfo(TAG_PACKAGE.get(position),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).publicSourceDir);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , pm.getApplicationInfo(TAG_PACKAGE.get(position),PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).publicSourceDir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/foldername/");
                     if(!dir.exists())
                        {
                            if(dir.mkdir()) ;//directory is created;
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this ,dir.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                     copy(file.getAbsoluteFile(), dir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Exception :

```
  exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/folder: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

it is not working , thnks

Comment: Is it IOException... Permission Denied? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978524/android-ioexception-permission-denied

Comment: no no , java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/foldername: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Comment: i created it already , but dnt work, same exception every time

Comment: Sorry, I have removed the recent comment after reading your codes...

Comment: I don't think your `copy()` function will work correctly since you doesn't check whether the file is really a file or not...

Comment: try this idea http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-copy-directory-in-java/ or use Apache IO Commons FileUtils library

Comment: in src is cumming "/system/app/abc.apk" but in des "/storage/sdcard0/folder"

Comment: again same exception 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/folder: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

Comment: @stackoverflow If you are getting any error while development then atleast post the error with your code which makes sense for others to understand your issues and provide solutions being developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to copy a file to a folder, but without specifying the destination file name.

I guess you want to append the file name to the destination path :

```
copy(file.getAbsoluteFile(), new File(dir, file.getName()));
```

Comment: and i try another thing 10 min ago , that also working, by the way thanks for your help